# jQuery push() returns error "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

this code gives me an error when submitting he form "undefined is not a function in line 21" and I don't know why

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$("form[name=dForm]").submit(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serializeObject();
        data.push({name:"bonjour",value:bonjour});

 // do something here ...

})
```

or it must be an array not an object?

Comment: looks like data is an object and not an array..

Comment: push is a Javascipt function. Not of jQuery

Comment: yes, and I dont know how to make it in array. because I have a multiple forms with same selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`serializeObject` returns `o` which is defined at the top of the function as `{}`.

`push` is a method of Array objects, not plain objects. It puts an item onto the end of an array.

Plain objects are unordered. There isn't an "end" to put the item onto, so it doesn't make sense for there to be a `push` method.

You, presumably,  want to just create a new property with a given name and value.

```
data.push({name:"bonjour",value:bonjour});
```

should be

```
data.bonjour = bonjour;
```

Comment: @Shashank — What does that have to do with anything? This is about assigning a new value, not reading an existing one.